# Google ad is going out of div

Tags: html, css

I know this was asked before, but I couldn't find a solution.
I've tried to give it a specific width, float left, and everything which can be imagined. Nothing helps.
Google ad is in my articles, I also created a div for it.!

[You can see the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWhsq.png)

However it works fine when watching on PC, but not on mobile.

You can see the website here: https://hearthstonehungary.hu/node/uj-lap-conjurers-calling (or check any other article - it's Hungarian language!).

Comment: Hi there, [please submit your code onto StackOverflow rather than linking to your website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of **Google Ads** including **Responsive Ads** and Google also provide proper documentation for all types of Ads.

> **Choose Ads Format** - [Reference Link](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722124?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en)
>
> **About responsive display ads** - [Reference Link](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6363750?hl=en)
>
> **Create a responsive display ad** - [Reference Link](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9267035?hl=en&visit_id=636899726492598155-1206772651&rd=1)